# Using JavaScript to insert text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get text to display using JavaScript but I can't seem to get it working, and I am not entirely clear on why.

It seems to be picked up, but I can't seem to see it actually showing anywhere.

This is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('.set1').each(function() {
    jQuery(this).before(jQuery('<img>').text("Some Text put here with Javascript... "));
});
</script>

<div class="image_carousel">
    <div id="foo1">
<img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/vision-db-1.png" class="set1" alt="Photography | Chad Pickard and Paul McLean" width="679" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/vision-db-2.png" class="set1" alt="Photography | Chad Pickard and Paul McLean" width="679" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/vision-db-3.png" class="set1" alt="Photography | Chad Pickard and Paul McLean" width="692" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/vision-7.png" class="set1" alt="Photography | Chad Pickard and Paul McLean" width="339" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/vision-8.png" class="set1" alt="Photography | Chad Pickard and Paul McLean" width="338" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/vision-db-4.png" class="set1" alt="Photography | Chad Pickard and Paul McLean" width="691" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/vision-11.png" class="set1" alt="Photography | Chad Pickard and Paul McLean" width="339" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/vision-12.png" class="set1" alt="Photography | Chad Pickard and Paul McLean" width="339" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/smug-1.png" class="set1" alt="Photography | Chad Pickard and Paul McLean" width="710" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/smug-2.png" class="set1" alt="Photography | Chad Pickard and Paul McLean" width="710" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/smug-3.png" class="set1" alt="Photography | Chad Pickard and Paul McLean" width="710" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/smug-4.png" class="set1" alt="Photography | Chad Pickard and Paul McLean" width="710" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/smug-5.png" class="set1" alt="Photography | Chad Pickard and Paul McLean" width="710" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/volt-4.png" class="set2" alt="Photography | Rory DCS" width="675" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/volt-1.png" class="set2" alt="Photography | Rory DCS" width="675" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/volt-7.png" class="set2" alt="Photography | Rory DCS" width="675" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/volt-9.png" class="set2" alt="Photography | Rory DCS" width="675" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/volt-3.png" alt="Photography | Rory DCS" width="675" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/volt-11.png" class="set2" alt="Photography | Rory DCS" width="675" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/hay-5.png" class="set3" alt="Photography | Alex Sainsbury" width="312" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/hay-4.png" class="set3" alt="Photography | Alex Sainsbury" width="300" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/hay-2.png" class="set3" alt="Photography | Alex Sainsbury" width="279" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/hay-3.png" class="set3" alt="Photography | Alex Sainsbury" width="292" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/hay-1.png" class="set3" alt="Photography | Alex Sainsbury" width="308" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/gana-1.png" class="set4" alt="Photography | Robert Charbonnet" width="675" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/gana-2.png" class="set4" alt="Photography | Robert Charbonnet" width="300" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/gana-3.png" class="set4" alt="Photography | Robert Charbonnet" width="300" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/gana-4.png" class="set4" alt="Photography | Robert Charbonnet" width="300" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/Peregrine-Shot_03-4.png" alt="Photography | David Goldman" width="675" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/Peregrine-Shot_09-84.png" alt="Photography | David Goldman" width="300" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/Peregrine-Shot_10-192.png" alt="Photography | David Goldman" width="300" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/Peregrine-Shot_16-48.png" alt="Photography | David Goldman" width="675" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/Peregrine-Shot_17-131.png" alt="Photography | David Goldman" width="300" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/ss2011-shot05-173.png" alt="Photography | David Goldman" width="300" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/ss2011-shot06-72-1.png" alt="Photography | David Goldman" width="300" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/vc-db-1.png" alt="Photography | Chad Pickard and Paul McLean" width="672" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/vc-3.png" alt="Photography | Chad Pickard and Paul McLean" width="343" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/vc-4.png" class="set1" alt="Photography | Chad Pickard and Paul McLean" width="342" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/vc-db-2.png" class="set1" alt="Photography | Chad Pickard and Paul McLean" width="671" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/vc-7.png" class="set1" alt="Photography | Chad Pickard and Paul McLean" width="298" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/vc-8.png" class="set1" alt="Photography | Chad Pickard and Paul McLean" width="299" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/vc-db-3.png" class="set1" alt="Photography | Chad Pickard and Paul McLean" width="694" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/vc-db-4.png" class="set1" alt="Photography | Chad Pickard and Paul McLean" width="685" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/vc-13.png" class="set1" alt="Photography | Chad Pickard and Paul McLean" width="341" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/vc-14.png" class="set1" alt="Photography | Chad Pickard and Paul McLean" width="343" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/vc-15.png" class="set1" alt="Photography | Chad Pickard and Paul McLean" width="342" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/lurve-5.png" class="set1" alt="Photography | Chad Pickard and Paul McLean" width="301" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/lurve-2.png" class="set1" alt="Photography | Chad Pickard and Paul McLean" width="673" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/lurve-3.png"  class="set1"alt="Photography | Chad Pickard and Paul McLean" width="301" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/vampire-weekend.png" class="set2" alt="Photography | Alan Clarke" width="660" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/grizzle-bear.png" class="set2" alt="Photography | Alan Clarke" width="660" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/tg-5.png" class="set3" alt="Photography | Harley Weir" width="588" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/tg-11.png" class="set3" alt="Photography | Harley Weir" width="343" height="450" /><img src="http://www.dwmu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/tg-12.png" class="set3" alt="Photography | Harley Weir" width="341" height="450" />
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <a class="prev" id="foo1_prev" href="#"><span>prev</span></a>
    <a class="next" id="foo1_next" href="#"><span>next</span></a>
    <div class="logbox" id="foo1_log"><p>Click the previous- or next-button</p></div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If I read that right, you're trying to put text in an image tag... is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: Am I the only one missing the CSS part of this?

Comment: @melihcelik: That's jQuery, not really CSS. Tagging and editing as such.

Comment: @melihcelik And he might also well be a she...

Comment: I am a she. I am trying to get the text to display above the image but is it not displaying correctly due to the fact that it's sat within an image tag?

Comment: Warning: Many of those images are probably **NSFW** for a lot of folks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want to put the text before the image?

http://jsfiddle.net/pixelass/nBVwz/

```
$('.set1').each(function() {
    $(this).before('<span>Some Text put here with Javascript... </span>');
});
```

or   http://jsfiddle.net/pixelass/nBVwz/1/  to use the alt value of the image

```
$('.set1').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).attr('alt');//get the alt value

    $(this).before('<span>' + text + '</span>');// put a span with the alt value before the image
});
```

Comment: updated my answer to pick the alt of the image and display it before the image

Answer (score 4):

First, your script is executing before the document has finished loading. Use `ready` to execute a callback once the DOM has fully loaded. Second, you need to place the text somewhere that makes sense (i.e. not inside an `img` element). This is one option:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".set1").each(function() {
        jQuery(this).before("<p>Some Text put here with Javascript...");
    });
});
```

A simple demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cRRVX/

Answer (score 2):

You need to 1) wait for the document to be loaded and 2) you need to put text into something other than an image tag like a span or div in order to show in the page and 3) you can just put the content right into the argument for the `.before()` method like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.set1').each(function() {
        jQuery(this).before('<span>Some Text put here with Javascript... </span>');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you mean the 'alt' or the 'title' [attributes](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
jQuery(this).before(jQuery('<img>').attr("alt", "Some Text put here with Javascript... "));
```

etc.